# How to ensure proper TextBlock Text wrapping within a TreeView WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make it so that my text in a textblock automatically wraps depending on the size of the window.

For example, this is some of the XAML code I have:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Message ID">
                                <TextBlock Text="The message ID determines which messages should be assigned the values in this row. This should be a hex value and applies only to the
                                           fourth byte and onwards of message data." MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</TreeViewItem>
```

Now this does wrap the text depending on the size of the window, however it does not account for the fact that the textblock starts to the right of the window due to the nature of TreeView and this is how the wrapping looks like:
[Wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0xPG.png)

As you can see the text wraps correctly assuming that the textblock starts at the left side of the window (which it does not due to the treeview) and as a result some of the text is cut off. I have asked bing AI multiple times for a solution and done some googling and have gotten vague answers regarding a "Converter" however I have been unable to make these solutions work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any great solution for your case, but at least let me show you a tricky workaround:

Create a value converter that will adjust the `TextBlocks` inside `TreeViewItem`s:

```cs
public class AdjustingValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double Variable { get; set; } = 0;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is double doubleValue
            ? Math.Max(doubleValue + Variable, 0)
            : value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

then as resources:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AdjustingValueConverter
        x:Key="WidthValueConverter"
        Variable="-50" />
    <Style
        x:Key="TreeViewTextBlock"
        TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource WidthValueConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

now on each `TextBlock`:

```xml
<TreeViewItem
    Header="Message Types">
    <TextBlock
        Style="{StaticResource TreeViewTextBlock}"
        Text="The message types GUI is the window where you can add or delete your filter rules for the incoming stream of messages."
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: I just tried the code and it works. Can you share code around your `TreeView`? How you are placing your `TreeView` to be specific.

Comment: I'm gonna post you my whole XAML code: https://hastebin.com/share/rebebuwova.xml

Comment: Weird. I just pasted your code to a plain WPF project and the text is wrapped and not cut off.

Comment: Just pasted the XAML into a new plain WPF project on visual studio 2022 and exact same issue. Are you doing anything differently?

Comment: Sorry. You are right. The `TextBlock`'s width goes wider than it's parent.

Comment: Did the updated answer fix your issue?